# Performant malloc implementation for executable code

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc, x86-64

I am generating tons of small fragments of executable machine code dynamically, all of them with unpredictable sizes and lifetimes. Currently I am using a naive executable `mmap` preallocated region, but this is only provisional due to the eventual memory exhaustion. I did not implemented any memory reclamation mechanism and I do not want to: this is a hard problem (hard to debug bugs, fragmentation, multi-threading, etc.).

What I need is a library that implements the `malloc`/`free` protocol but with the executable bit enabled.

Is there any `malloc` implementation that offers this option (can be a compile-time flag)?

**Further details to answer comments:**

- My current platform is Linux on x86_64, but Windows and ARM 32/64 support will be welcome (but not a must).
- Memory never will be shared with different processes, but the allocator must be multi-threading aware and, if possible, scalable in this scenario.

Comment: it is system dependent. What is the system/arch?

Comment: Is this possible to use the same memory map for multiple executable in the same time ?

Comment: @bolov Question updated to answer you.

Comment: of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125756/allocate-executable-ram-in-c-on-linux , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936534/how-to-alloc-a-executable-memory-buffer

Comment: @Stargateur Do you mean if this `mmap` is shared or private? It's private and anonymous if it matters.

Comment: Do you need to be able to malloc() in one thread and free() the result in another?  Are you willing to set a fixed maximum memory size for the entire program throughout its lifetime?

Comment: @JohnZwinck If possible, I want to be able to `malloc()` on one thread and `free()` in another, but it isn't a must. Memory usage is currently unbounded, but it can be bounded if required. Anything better than my current "solution" (an unsafe hack that crashes the program when buffer is full) will be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use a pool (arena) allocator.  For example this one: https://github.com/philip-wernersbach/memory-pool-allocator .  The implementation calls `malloc()` once during initialization, but on most systems if you call `malloc()` with a large enough size, it will use `mmap()`.  So you could modify this library to call `mprotect()` or similar to make the pages executable, and maybe even replace the `malloc()` call with `mmap()` directly (because the threshold at which `malloc()` calls `mmap()` is configurable, so you may not want to rely on it).