# How to inline ASM byte statement in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have written a simple binary app to produce a c source file, I feed it a memory address and split the string to print final source. I am new to Rust, how can this be improved? I also did some search and replace which gives me "" at the end, I am unsure of why this is given the replace.

Here is app output:

```
~/Research/split_mem_mk_src(master*) » cargo run                                                                                
   Compiling split_mem_mk_src v0.1.0 (/Users/RSRCH/Research/split_mem_mk_src)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.46s
     Running `target/debug/split_mem_mk_src`
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  __asm__(".byte "0x62, 0x02, 0x55, 0xd4, 0x7f, 0xb5, 0xb1, 0x8e, 0xbf, 0xcd\"")
}
```

I want to end up with this...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  __asm__(".byte 0x62, 0x02, 0x55, 0xd4, 0x7f, 0xb5, 0xb1, 0x8e, 0xbf, 0xcd");
}
```

I would eventually like to just execute asm in rust and run though gdb, so any idea on this would be great. Happy to read docs. I found this https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/library-features/asm.html but didn't see execute byte statement like C.

App Source

````
fn main() {
    let n = 2;
    let text = "620255d47fb5b18ebfcd".to_string();
    let mem_addr = text.chars()
    .enumerate()
    .flat_map(|(i, c)| {
        if i != 0 && i % n == 0 {
            Some(' ')
        } else {
            None
        }
        .into_iter()
        .chain(std::iter::once(c))
    })
    .collect::<String>();
    let final_str = format!("0x{:?}", mem_addr.replace(" ", ", 0x"));
    println!("int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {{");
    println!("  __asm__(\".byte {:?})", final_str.replace("0x\"", "0x"));
    println!("}}");
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `{:?}`. This uses the `Debug` trait, which is only meant for debugging, always includes quotes around the string and escapes special characters, such as `"`. `Debug` isn't meant to be used to produce any kind of exact output.

What you want is the `Display` trait, which is the default trait when nothing is specified, therefore you can simply use `{}`.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed! Realise I got into bad habits with {:?}. Output now: __asm__(".byte 0x62, 0x02, 0x55, 0xd4, 0x7f, 0xb5, 0xb1, 0x8e, 0xbf, 0xcd");

Comment: Do you know anyway I can execute an x86 asm instruction directly with Rust in this format? ".byte 0x62, 0x02, 0x55, 0xd4, 0x7f, 0xb5, 0xb1, 0x8e, 0xbf, 0xcd"

Comment: @SecurityResearcher: You can if you use nightly and the `asm` feature gate: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=ffe0204fbeeb8fbe5bf7d3ed9a6c103b)

Comment: @Rodrigo Except this won't actually work because asm! Is compile time, while OP seems to want to generate assembly from a string.

Comment: @IvanC: Ah, I thought OP just wanted to output Rust source code instead of C.

Comment: @IvanC is correct I do wish to execute assembly from string. I am thinking I will have to write to file, build and then run with gdb - that's the best I have right now. At the moment I pipe to file, gcc and then run with gdb.

Comment: @SecurityResearcher this question might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856247/how-to-execute-raw-instructions-from-a-memory-buffer-in-rust